# Loudness Equalization - Why Music In Winamp Loses Some Volume?

Tags: drivers, audio, winamp, equalizer

When i use that option, music is increased in volume which is good, since otherwise music on my laptop does not sound loud or how i want it to sound even with all controls on max. However so far i have spotted on application where this has reverse effect - Winamp. While everywhere else music sounds loud, it sounds less loud in Winamp.

To better know what i am talking about, **[here is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=rqOzz3gm6WQ&hd=1)**.

So i have to constantly enable disable option depending what i am listening/watching to.

**FYI:** I have IDT Audio Control Panel.

Answer (score 2):

A loudness equalization simply normalizes the audio signal.  You can modify Winamp's equalizer to increase the overall audio gain to compensate for this (there is a main slider beside all of the ones to set individual frequency range gains).  Just slide this up a few decibels to compensate for the *perceived* reduction in volume (normalizing a song **does not** change the average volume of the signal).

Each application implements a normalization algorithm differently, and some amplify the signal before or afterwards.  Normalizing most songs will result in a either a perceived volume reduction or gain, depending on the audio signal itself.

Comment: Not really increases that much as it would with "Loudness Equalization". I think there is something else involved here.

Comment: @Boris_yo You can **drastically** increase the volume with the equalizer gain.  It will probably max out your speakers if you set it to the top.

Comment: Maxed everything but does not increase volume that much with loudness equalization enabled and disabled. Maybe it increases drastically if you have powerful speakers and not laptop speakers.